# numpy structured array inconsistency

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, structured-array

I'm writing a library that uses NumPy arrays and I have a scalar operation I would like to perform on *any* dtype. This works fine for most structured arrays, however I run into a problem when creating structured arrays with multiple dimensions for structured elements. As an example,

```
x = np.zeros(10, np.dtype('3float32,int8'))
print(x.dtype)
print(x.shape)
```

shows

```
[('f0', '<f4', (3,)), ('f1', 'i1')]
(10,)
```

but

```
x = np.zeros(10, np.dtype('3float32'))
print(x.dtype)
print(x.shape)
```

yields

```
float32
(10, 3)
```

that is, creating a structured array with a single multidimensional field appears to instead expand the array shape. This means that the number of dimensions for the last example is 2, not 1 as I was expecting. Is there anything I'm missing here, or a known workaround?

Comment: there are other more detailed ways of specifying a compound dtype.  You've just chosen a shorthand, and thus are subject its translation rules.

Comment: I don't think this is correct; there appears to be no way to get np.zeros to use a dtype of  dtype(('<f4', (3,))) to generate an array with ndims = 1!

Answer (score 0):

Use the same `dtype` notation as displayed in the first working example:

```
In [92]: x = np.zeros(3, np.dtype([('f0','<f4',(3,))]))

In [93]: x
Out[93]: 
array([([0., 0., 0.],), ([0., 0., 0.],), ([0., 0., 0.],)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4', (3,))])
```

I don't normally use the string shorthand,

```
In [99]: np.dtype('3float32')
Out[99]: dtype(('<f4', (3,)))     # no field name assigned

In [100]: np.zeros(3,_)
Out[100]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

A couple of comma separated strings creates named fields:

```
In [102]: np.dtype('3float32,i4')
Out[102]: dtype([('f0', '<f4', (3,)), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answers my question; for your second example, note that the shape of the array is (3, 3) and not (3,) -- that is, the dtype is now float32 and the ndims have been increased by one!

Comment: `Out[93]` is 1d, with 1 field.  What I'm trying to show is that the string shorthand is not adequate for defining a single field dtype.  You need to use the list of tuples approach.  My [100] example is same as yours; [99] just show the dtype that's actually used by `np.zeros`.  You want the longer dtype as displayed in [93]

Comment: The docs for the string shorthand specify "comma separated".  It may seem picky, but '3float32' is not comma separated.  To get a 1d, 1 field array you need to specify the field name.  It might instructive to do field access in the '3float32,int8' case.  Look at `x['f0']` and `x[['f0']]`.  One produces a 2d float array, the other a 1d 1 field array.

Comment: So the real issue is that numpy cannot create a structured dtype that does not have field names.

Comment: In my experience, fields with field names is an integral part of a compound dtype and structured array,  A nameless field does not make sense.